# What is the meaning of flow in this problem?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Consider a two dimensional vector field $X$ defined by $x'(t)=p(x,y), y'(t)=q(x,y)$, where $p$ and $q$ are differentiable functions.

Specifically I am trying to show that $\frac{d}{dt}A(\Omega_t)|_{t=0}=\int\int_{\Omega}(\frac{\partial p}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial q}{\partial y})dxdy$

I am using the area integral that states $A(\Omega_t)=\int\int_{\Omega_t} dxdy=\int\int_{\Omega}det(D\phi_t)dxdy$

My main issue is that I don't know what $D\phi_t$ is, which is the flow.

Comment: Okay, so it looks like you have called the components of your vector field $x'(t)$ and $y'(t)$ which suggests they represent a velocity field (since the primes generally indicate derivative). And you have the region you are integrating over represented 2 ways, $\Omega$ and $\Omega_t$. So I assume the region you are integrating over is changing with respect to time, carried along by the velocity field $(p,q)$ which is steady?

Comment: @MattDickau yes that is correct

Comment: So the equation you are trying to show, then, is just saying that *the rate of expansion of the region* is equal to the integral of *the divergence of the velocity field within the region*, at time zero. (It would be valid at any other time, too, if you replaced $t=0$ with $t=t'$ and $\Omega$ in the integral with $\Omega_{t'}$.) I believe the $D\phi_t$ is the *deformation gradient tensor*, the determinant of which gives the ratio of the deformed area to the original area, locally. Should be a way to figure out what that is from $p$ and $q$, but I'm afraid I don't know it offhand!

Answer (score 1):

$D\phi_t$ would be the *deformation gradient tensor*. To obtain it you would have to integrate the velocity vector field to get the deformation, then take its gradient. But actually you can do this problem without considering $D\phi_t$ at all.

Using the [Reynolds transport theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reynolds_transport_theorem):
$$\frac{d}{dt}A(\Omega_t)=\frac{d}{dt}\iint_{\Omega_t}dA=\iint_{\Omega_t}\frac{\partial}{\partial t}(1)dA+\int_{\partial\Omega_t}\vec v\cdot d\vec n$$

Where $d\vec n$ is $\vec ndl$, the normal vector to the boundary times a differential boundary element. The first term is zero since 1 is constant. Using the [divergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_theorem):
$$\int_{\partial\Omega_t}\vec v\cdot d\vec n=\iint_{\Omega_t}\nabla\cdot\vec v\,dA$$

So:
$$\frac{d}{dt}A(\Omega_t)=\iint_{\Omega_t}\nabla\cdot\vec v\,dA$$

Since $\nabla\cdot\vec v=\frac{\partial p}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial q}{\partial y}$ and $\Omega_0=\Omega$, evaluating this last line at $t=0$ gives you what you wanted to show.